# Not show Media library permission dialog in Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am building Xamarin iOS application which accesses media library.

I putted media library permission usage description in info.plist.

[image]

But it doesn't show permission request dialog when I call this method.

```
MPMediaQuery mq = new MPMediaQuery();
```

As permission authorization status is not determined, so the app is crashed at that time.

I checked the settings, but I can't see media permission, so I couldn't enable it manually.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During research, I found the solution here.

[Security Privacy Enhancements](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/security-privacy-enhancements/)

This happened because I used deprecated description key.
I resolved this issue by using **NSAppleMusicUsageDescription** instead.